# JavaScript Array filter with async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, async-await

The following function:

```
async function getPendingTransactions(address){
    var pendingBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock('pending');
    var i = 0;
    var pendingTransactions = await pendingBlock.transactions.filter(async function(txHash)  {
        var tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
        console.log(tx);
        if(tx != null) {
            return tx.from==address && tx.to == CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
        }
    });
    console.log(pendingTransactions);   
    return pendingTransactions;
}
```

The filter does not work and all transactions are displayed (console.log), and the filter loops seems to be processed afterwards. I guess it is a async/await problem.
How can I keep the the filter synchronous?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use an `async` function as a `filter` callback, because:

1. `filter` won't wait for the promises to be settled, and
2. `async` functions always return promises, and promises like all non-`null` objects are truthy, so as far as `filter` is concerned you're returning a flag saying you should keep the element

In this case, you can use `Promise.all` to wait for all the transactions to be retrieved and then filter the results; see comments:

```
async function getPendingTransactions(address) {
    const pendingBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock("pending");
    // *** Get the transactions by creating an array of promises and then waiting
    // via `await` for all of them to settle
    const transactions = await Promise.all(
        pendingBlock.transactions.map(txHash => web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash))
    );
    // *** Filter them
    const pendingTransactions = transactions.filter(
        tx => tx && tx.from == address && tx.to == CONTRACT_ADDRESS
    );
    return pendingTransactions;
}
```

All of the calls to `web3.eth.getTransaction` will be started in parallel, then we wait for all of them to settle via `await Promise.all(/*...*/)`, then filter the result and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution below is using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library, which supports async `filter`:

```
async function getPendingTransactions(address) {
    const pendingBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock('pending');
    return pipeAsync(
        pendingBlock.transactions,
        filter(async txHash => {
            const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
            console.log(tx);
            if(tx != null) {
                return tx.from == address && tx.to == CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Function `getPendingTransactions` will return `AsyncIterable<Transaction>`, which you can easily loop through:

```
for await (const t of getPendingTransactions('address')) {
    console.log(t); // transaction details
}
```